# awk: chop stuff off beginning of line according to regex

Tags: regex, awk

Say I have a few lines of output that look like this:

```
 blah <foo> I want this
 baz < nom> I want this too
 bit <@hi>   And this...
```

How do I use awk to chop off everything before, and including, the first ">" character on each line?

Comment: Can there be more than one `>` on a line?

Comment: Yes, there can. I ended up using sed, as per jaypal's answer.

Comment: A good choice I'd have used `cut` myself but jaypals second sed is fine too. I'm curious though - why did you specifically ask for an awk solution (and then accept a sed answer)?

Comment: @EdMorton Technically he hasn't accepted it `:P`. Though I agree both of your recent `cut` answers are idiomatic and probably the right way to go about it.

Comment: @jaypal It's always hard to know what to do when someone asks for an answer that uses a specific tool. Are they asking because they know they need to make future enhancements to the solution and that tool is the right one to build on? Or are they asking because they've heard of that tool and think it might provide a solution but actually don't care what tool they use? I usually assume the latter but then you risk getting slammed by other responders for not answering the question. Quite a dilemma...

Comment: @EdMorton I asked for awk because I forgot that sed and cut existed! Also, because I wanted to learn a bit more about awk I suppose.

Comment: It;s always risky to ask for a specific implementation of a solution rather than asking for a solution because you might just get what you asked for and it might not be the best solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets not forget cut, this is what it was invented for:

```
cut -d\> -f2- file
```

Comment: Perfect example of the Unix philosophy :) Accepted, since it is a better way than awk.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have `>` character once you can do a simple `sed` substitution:

```
sed 's/.*>//' file
```

If there can be many the above greedy (`*`) will consume everything up to the last `>` character. In that case, you are better off doing:

```
sed 's/[^>]*>//' file
```

Answer (score 2):

This may do (if you have one `>`)

```
awk -F\> '{print $2}' file
 I want this
 I want this too
   And this...
```

Answer (score 0):

Using awk you can do:

```
awk '{sub(/^[^.]*>/, "");} 1' file
 I want this
 I want this too
   And this...
```

Or using sed:

```
sed 's/^[^.]*>//' file
 I want this
 I want this too
   And this...
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
awk -F">"  '{print $1">"}' filename
```